# I would like to know how the Google search autocomplete function works

Tags: javascript, database, google-chrome, search, server

I'm now starting a project to create an api that does autocomplete.
While collecting references, ask questions to know the structure and structure that is auto-completed when you enter a search term in real time on Google or other search engine sites, and the techniques used.

The structure I know briefly is the same.

Client -> Enter search term -> Server -> Query query -> DB

Client <- search term input <- server <- search term query <-DB

Thanks for the comment. I don't know in detail yet, so I'll tell you the scenario I want to know. Suppose a user enters the alphabet of's','t','a','c','k' as a search word after accessing a search engine site. Then, at this time, the client and server want to know if they communicate in real time as soon as the alphabet is entered

If so, is the communication method ajax? Is there a way to use the data necessary for the auto-completion function in the local area where the client is located other than real-time communication with the server?

Because it is limited to use a server to place an api that functions as auto-completion, there is a problem that it will be difficult to handle the traffic generated when real-time input occurs.

Comment: It's complicated :) your structure seems basically right (from a high level); do you have a question about a specific part?